# How do I show a list of nodes referenced by a field?

Tags: views, nodes

I created two content types: *News Agency* and *News*.
The *News* content type has the *Headline*, *Title*, *Body*, and *News agency name* (a reference to a *News Agency* node) fields. The *News agency* content type has the *News agency name* and *Publisher* fields.

I need to show the news related to particular news agency. I am trying to set a relationship, but it still doesn't show result.

[image: Image of News Content type]

Comment: here related new agency field reference to NEWS AGENCY. How to get the views of news related to particular news agency.

Comment: Please include information about the view that you are trying to setup, your question is very broad as it is.

Answer (score 0):

The "Entity reference" field has a few options about how to display the referenced entities (Label, entire node, Node ID).

But you're referencing News agencies from News nodes, not the other way around. So you're able to choose how News agencies are listed on News pages through the "Manage display" settings in Content type.

If you want to list nodes on the News agency pages you need to use Views to create "backwards" Relationship:

1. Create Views listing News, Block display
2. Add a Contextual filter for the Entity reference field relating to the News agency and configure it
   `When the filter value is NOT available`
   **Provide default value**
   **Content ID from URL**
   `When the filter value IS available or a default is provided`
   **Specify validation criteria**
   **Content**
   **Related? News agency**

   Test the configuration by entering one of your News Agency NIDs into the Views Preview field. You should see News nodes that relate to that agency in the view results.
3. If everything is working as expected place the Block into a region in your theme and configure it to only appear on the News Agency pages, and configure the filter option for the reference.

Now when you visit News Agency pages you'll see a list of all News that relate to that agency.